# Starting Tab - UITabBarController Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

I've just created a tab `UIViewController` in Swift, brand new, no code. 
I wanted to know how I could change which tab the app starts on. For example, it has view 1 and view 2. At the bottom it has two tabs, tab 1 and tab 2. How could I get it to where the tab and page it starts on is tab 2, view 2. Instead of always opening and starting on the first tab. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

i think its natural that the `UITabViewController` shows the first `UIViewController`.

edit:
The best solution is to subclass the `UITabBarController` and to change the selected index in it's viedDidLoad() Delegate:

1. Create a subclass file of `UITabBarController` (File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class)
   [image]
2. Set this new file as the Class in the UITabBarController of your Storyboard.
   [image]
3. Add in the new file:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
       // or: tabBarController.selectedViewController = myViewController
   }
   ```

Comment: nice quick and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. In your viewWillAppear method.

override func viewWillAppear() {

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Enter your tabBar storyboard ID here") as! UITabBarController

vc.selectedIndex = 0

self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

- The selectedIndex 0 is the first tabBar. You can change this to whichever tabbar you want to open
- Set a storyboard ID in main.storyboard identity ID